# Create new column based of subset of strings in another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create new a column in my dataframe, based off a subset of strings in another
This is my dataframe

```
df =structure(list(Combination = c("BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", 
"BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", 
"BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Radio", "Stationary_Radio", 
"Stationary_Radio", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", 
"Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT", "Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_PIT", "Stationary_PIT", "Stationary_Acousitc_PIT", 
"Stationary_Acousitc_PIT", "Stationary_Acousitc_PIT", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Satellite", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Satellite", "Animalborne_Satellite", 
"Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Radio_PIT", "Stationary_Radio_PIT", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Satellite", "Controlled_Satellite", "Controlled_Satellite", 
"Controlled_Satellite", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival_PIT", "Animalborne_Archival_PIT", "Animalborne_Archival_PIT", 
"Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival", "Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_PIT", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_PIT", "Stationary_Acoustic_PIT", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Archival", "Controlled_Archival", 
"Controlled_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Radio", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Satellite", 
"Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Satellite", "Stationary_Satellite", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic_Radio", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Radio", "Stationary_Acoustic_Radio", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-245L))
```

I want a new column where the values relate to some strings so for every value that has a `Acoustic`, `radio`, or `PIT` the value in the new column should be `receiver based` and for everything else it should be `non receiver based`. But for columns that have `acoustic` and `satellite` in the column I need the value in the new column to say `Both`.

I have tried the `ifelse` command using this code

```
df$Type = ifelse(df$Combination == "Acoustic", 'Non Receiver Based', 'Receiver Based')
```

But it's calling all of them `receiver based` and I don't know how to incorporate all the arguments I am suggesting above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` to check if a certain pattern occurs in a string, and then use if-else statements to decide on your cases. Since `if()` is not vectorized, you need to wrap it in `Vectorize()` to use it in `mutate()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

match <- Vectorize(function(string) {
  if (!grepl("Acoustic|radio|PIT", string)) {
    "non receiver based"
  } else if ((grepl("Acoustic", string)) &
             (grepl("Satellite", string))) {
    "Both"
  } else "receiver based"
})

df %>% mutate(new_var = match(Combination))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl` to check if one of the words appears in the string. The pattern consists of the words separated by `|`, to say check if either of this words appears in the string:

```r
min_string = c("BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "Stationary_Radio_PIT", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival")

pattern = paste0(c("Acoustic", "radio", "PIT"), collapse = "|")
ifelse(!grepl(pattern, min_string), 'Non Receiver Based', 
       ifelse(grepl("Acoustic", min_string) & grepl("Satellite", min_string), "Both",
              "Receiver Based"))
#[1] "Both"               "Receiver Based"     "Non Receiver Based"
```

A `dplyr` alternative is to use `case_when`, which might be a bit friendlier to understand:

```r
library(dplyr) 
case_when(!grepl(pattern, min_string) ~ "Non Receiver",
             grepl("Acoustic", min_string) & grepl("Satellite", min_string) ~ "Both",
             grepl(pattern, min_string) ~ "Receiver")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some functions from `tidyverse`.
Below, I create a new column called `new_col` which is your desired output:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic")==T | str_detect(Combination, "Radio")==T | str_detect(Combination, "PIT"), "receiver based", "non receiver based")) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic")==T & str_detect(Combination, "Satellite")==T, "Both", new_col))
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this be helpfull to you?

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(new_col = case_when(
    str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic_Satellite") ~ "both",
    str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic") ~ "Receiver Based",
    str_detect(Combination, "Radio") ~ "Receiver Based",
    str_detect(Combination, "PIT") ~ "Receiver Based"))

df2 <- replace(df1, is.na(df1), "non receiver based")
```

It is a rather dirty solution, I am sure someone will find a better one and only works if Acoustic_Satelite is a single word in your dataset but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

A simple step by step way could be:

```
df$Type <- "non receiver based"
i <- grepl("Acoustic", df$Combination)
df$Type[i | grepl("radio|PIT", df$Combination)] <- "receiver based"
df$Type[i & grepl("Satellite", df$Combination)] <- "Both"
rm(i)

df
#                       Combination               Type
#1          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#2          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#3          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#4          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#5          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#6          BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite               Both
#7             Animalborne_Archival non receiver based
#8             Animalborne_Archival non receiver based
#9             Animalborne_Archival non receiver based
#10             Controlled_Acoustic     receiver based
#...
```

---

Just for fun a Benchmark:

```
library(tidyverse)

match <- Vectorize(function(string) {  #Maybe another name would be better
  if (!grepl("Acoustic|radio|PIT", string)) {
    "non receiver based"
  } else if ((grepl("Acoustic", string)) &
             (grepl("Satellite", string))) {
    "Both"
  } else "receiver based"
})

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
Maël1 = local({pattern = paste0(c("Acoustic", "radio", "PIT"), collapse = "|")
cbind(df, Type=ifelse(!grepl(pattern, df$Combination), 'Non Receiver Based', 
       ifelse(grepl("Acoustic", df$Combination) & grepl("Satellite", df$Combination), "Both",
              "Receiver Based"))) }),

Maël2 = local({pattern = paste0(c("Acoustic", "radio", "PIT"), collapse = "|")
  cbind(df, Type=case_when(!grepl(pattern, df$Combination) ~ "Non Receiver",
             grepl("Acoustic", df$Combination) & grepl("Satellite", df$Combination) ~ "Both",
             grepl(pattern, df$Combination) ~ "Receiver")) }),

"Lukas Unterschuetz" = local({df %>% mutate(new_var = match(Combination))}),

Leonardo19 = local({df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic")==T | str_detect(Combination, "Radio")==T | str_detect(Combination, "PIT"), "receiver based", "non receiver based")) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic")==T & str_detect(Combination, "Satellite")==T, "Both", new_col)) }),

procerus = local({df1 <- df %>% mutate(new_col = case_when(
    str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic_Satellite") ~ "both",
    str_detect(Combination, "Acoustic") ~ "Receiver Based",
    str_detect(Combination, "Radio") ~ "Receiver Based",
    str_detect(Combination, "PIT") ~ "Receiver Based"))
    replace(df1, is.na(df1), "non receiver based")}),

GKi = local({df$Type <- "non receiver based"
  i <- grepl("Acoustic", df$Combination, fixed=TRUE)
  df$Type[i | grepl("radio|PIT", df$Combination)] <- "receiver based"
  df$Type[i & grepl("Satellite", df$Combination, fixed=TRUE)] <- "Both"
  rm(i)
  df})
)
```

Result

```
  expression              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 Maël1              531.63µs 562.63µs     1751.    31.1KB     2.02   865     1
2 Maël2              776.25µs 820.19µs     1204.    44.4KB     2.02   596     1
3 Lukas Unterschuetz   5.52ms   5.76ms      172.    11.8KB     4.13    83     2
4 Leonardo19           2.91ms   3.07ms      307.    50.6KB     6.26   147     3
5 procerus             1.89ms   2.02ms      457.    66.9KB     6.24   220     3
6 GKi                 214.9µs 231.51µs     4241.    11.8KB     2.02  2099     1
```